# Using IPNAT API under winCE 6

Tags: sockets, windows-ce, nat, portforwarding, tcp

Hi I am under Windows CE and I need to write a small application for port forwarding. So I have to use the NAT (Network Address Translation) driver to do that. Does this driver have any documentation? I didn't find any thing under msdn. Probably I will only use IOCTL_IP_NAT_DELETE_TICKET and IOCTL_IP_NAT_CREATE_TICKET which are defined in ipnat.h.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no documentation for this feature exists in MSDN or anywhere else.

The comments in the ipnat.h header should get you some of the way though.

If you have access to Platform Builder, there's a code sample demonstrating how to use these ioctl's. For Platform Builder 7.0, this sample is located in C:\WINCE700\PUBLIC\SERVERS\OAK\SAMPLES\UPNP\IGD.

Open the NAT driver by calling CreateFile on the "NAT0:" device, then use the returned HANDLE in the DeviceIoControl calls.

IOCTL_IP_NAT_CREATE_TICKET and IOCTL_IP_NAT_DELETE_TICKET both take an input parameter of type IP_NAT_CREATE_TICKET, and return nothing in the output buffer.